# GREP: how to match positive or negative digit?

Tags: grep, styles, adobe-indesign

I would to apply a text style on a percentage (%) number according to is polarity.
Like, if I get a `-21%` so I would Indesign apply the style1, if it's `21%`, ID must apply another style.

This is my starting point to match content:

```
\.^-\d+\K%  for negative digit

^+\+\d+\K% for positive
```

If someone can help me, it's my first time using GREP style in ID.

Thanks

Comment: Crazy, it works like a charm !! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For positive values use

```
^[+]?[0-9]+%$
```

For negative values, use

```
^-[0-9]+%$
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[+]?` - an optional `+` char
- `-` - a `-` char
- `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits
- `%` - a `%` symbol
- `$` - end of string.